# Align author text on last line of quote if there's room, otherwise put it on new line

Tags: android

[image]

Above is an example of the output I want. Notice that "by John" is aligned to the right on the last line of the quote.

[image]

If there's not enough space, then I would like the author to appear on a new line, but still be right aligned.

Answer (score 1):

you have to take two different TextViews in this case and give gravity="right" for the second one

Answer (score 0):

replace your xml with this...

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 android:padding="5dip" >

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="top"
android:layout_marginBottom="3dip"
android:layout_marginTop="3dip"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="5"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:text="Loren ipsum Loren ipsum Loren ipsum Loren ipsum Loren ipsum Loren ipsum Loren ipsum Loren ipsum Loren ipsum Loren ipsum Loren ipsum"
    android:textColor="#454545"
    android:textSize="9sp" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/by"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
   android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:text="by john"
    android:textColor="#454545"
    android:textSize="9sp" />


 </RelativeLayout>

  </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: @LucasTan If not enough space on the last line, then it should be on another line but still aligned right.Its works. check it....

Answer (score 0):

use this : hope this will work you

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dip" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="2dp"
        android:text="Loren ipsum Loren ipsum Loren ipsum Loren ipsum Loren ipsum Loren  Loren n ipsum Loren ipsum Loren ipsum Loren  Loren ipsum"
        android:textColor="#454545"
        android:textSize="9sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/by"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:text="by john"
        android:textColor="#454545"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:textSize="9sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```